# How does this short exact sequence work (Bockstein)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

[image]

I wish to confirm how the short exact sequence $$0\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{f}\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{g}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
actually works.

Is it correct to say that:
$$f(a+p\mathbb{Z})=ap+p^2\mathbb{Z}$$
$$g(b+p^2\mathbb{Z})=b\pmod{p}+p\mathbb{Z}$$? This is my current understanding that $f$ is the "times $p$" map and $g$ is the "mod $p$" map.

Q2) I am a bit puzzled by what McCleary writes as "we have written $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\cong p\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ as the kernel". I understand that $p\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ is the kernel of the "mod $p$" map $g$, but I don't see where has he "written it"?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of the map $g$ formally is $p\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$. He has written $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ instead, using an isomorphism. So he has indeed "written it" the simplified way.
Otherwise everything seems all right. There are also all the other exact sequences, with multiplication by $np$, for $n=1,\ldots (p-1)$. This gives $p-1$ inequivalent non-split extensions
$$
0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p \xrightarrow{\cdot np} \mathbb{Z}/p^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\rightarrow 0.
$$
Then the kernel is $(\mathbb{Z}/p)/np(\mathbb{Z}/p)\cong \mathbb{Z}/p$.

Comment: Just to check, did he write $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ in the short exact sequence? Or did he write it in the sentence: "where we have written ..."? Thanks. (I am a bit confused since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ appears quite a few times in the screenshot text, I am not sure which one the author means.)

Comment: He wrote it on both places, otherwise you would not know what is meant. I am also confused - do you have problems with the image perhaps? I can write here what he says. He has an exact sequence starting $0\rightarrow p\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ and then says " where we have written $\mathbb{Z}/p$ instead of $p\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ (they are isomorphic anyway).

Comment: Ah I see, I understand now. So if he doesn't use the isomorphism, the exact sequence should be: $0\to p\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\to p\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}\to 0$? (edited)

Comment: Great. I think I understood it finally. Thanks.